# log into unix server from windows

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I want to log into remote UNIX server from windows through batch file or some script. I have a username and password for that srever. i have to execute the script in unix server with inputs from the windows.

i tried ssh from windows but it throws error as not recognized command. for rsh the password need to be given manually. i need to automate that.

I am new to unix and scripting can any buddy help me with some sample scripts or codings.

Thanks,
Go

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? and why have you tagged this question as `internet-explorer-8`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to install [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), an SSH implementation for Windows.  It includes plink, a command-line SSH tool, as well as the GUI version.

That should sort you out.

Comment: i cant any external softwares.. i m in automation part and  have write application to do that..

Comment: Windows simply does not have SSH functionality built in. You *will* have to pull in some external dependancies to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a command line utility you could use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), its an intergration of some core linux tools and libraries for windows. There are plenty of guides how to use and install ssh with cygwin so I won't write another one here.

Next possibilty would be to just use a LiveCD of your favourite Linux ditribution or install a second OS on you computer, if you do not rely on any other windows tools for the task you are trying to do.